# making canvas register mouse move with div over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, event-listener

I have a `<canvas>` element that spans the width and height of my webpage, like a background. It has interactive elements that rely on mouse coordinates. When the canvas was in it's own block (i.e. nothing over it) the interactive elements worked fine. But now that it's got divs over it it's not picking up any of the mouse interactions.

Below is my javascript code for the mousemove stuff. Why would items on top affect it picking up mouse xy coordinates, and how do I fix it?

```
var mouse = {x:-100,y:-100};
var mouseOnScreen = false;

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', MouseMove, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', MouseOut, false);

var MouseMove = function(e) {
    if (e.layerX || e.layerX == 0) {
        //Reset particle positions
        mouseOnScreen = true;


        mouse.x = e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        mouse.y = e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
    }
}

var MouseOut = function(e) {
    mouseOnScreen = false;
    mouse.x = -100;
    mouse.y = -100; 
}

    var update = function(){
    var i, dx, dy, sqrDist, scale;
     //...... this chunk is the only part of the function that references the mouse
        dx = parts[i].x - mouse.x;
        dy = parts[i].y - mouse.y;
        sqrDist =  Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

        if (sqrDist < 20){
            parts[i].r = true;
        }       
        .....
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with this code I found from another SO answer that I modified a bit.

```
function simulate(e) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window,
    0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        canvas.dispatchEvent(evt);
        console.log("Emulated.");
    }

    $("body > section, body > header").each(function(){
        this.addEventListener("mousemove", simulate);
    });
```

Also, as a side note. Changed original layerX and layerY in mouse code to offsetX and offsetY to work in firefox (in addition to all other browsers)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you don't need the top divs to be mouse-aware then set their CSS `pointer-events:none;` and the mouse events will filter down to your canvas underneath.</strike>  Questioner needs responsive buttons placed over the canvas.

If the top divs do need to respond to mouse events, you might have to listen for mouse events on the window and convert those to canvas coordinates that your app can respond to.

You can listen for `mousemove` events on the `window` and get all moves -- even when over button elements. Also listen for `mouseout` events on the `window`. Since the canvas spans the window, you know mouseout happens when mouseevent.clientX & mouseevent.clientY report the coordinates are outside the window

Comment: yea, I need to click on a button or two in the top divs, so that won't work. Good to know though! Any chance you know how to do the mouse events-to-canvas coordinates part?

Comment: Perhaps draw your buttons on the canvas using `fillRect` and `fillText` and then respond when the use clicks the canvas in the button rectangle?

Comment: Since the canvas doesn't need to be interacted with other than mouse position, I'd rather have it just track mouse position than re-design the divs I have over it. The divs are much more complex

Comment: Fair enough...then go with using `window.onmousemove` and `window.onmouseout` to drive your canvas. Good luck with your project! :-)